# Location of electrical relay

Tags: electrical

I have electrical baseboard heaters, electrician told me I have a bad RELAY, we have a bi-level I cannot find the relay in the wall, how can I find the relay

Comment: The electrician told you it's bad without looking at it or even knowing where it is?  I hope he didn't charge you for that.

Answer (score 3):

Code says every piece of electrical equipment, and every splice, must be inside an enclosed junction box (for fire safety). The cover of that box must remain accessible forever without removal of wall materials or damaging the building finish in any way.  The only thing buried in the wall are continuous wires.

Probably 95% of the junction boxes in the home are hiding underneath switches and receptacles.  But they are unlikely to have wiring that isn't related to those switches and receptacles, so I wouldn't go hunting there.

Sometimes this is violated (e.g. unqualified people installing "built-in" cabinets right on top of a receptacle without doing something appropriate there), but by and large the rule will hold.

As such, you can be largely confident the relay is somewhere accessible. Typically in the heater itself (does it make a click when it cycles on/off? Heaters have no reason to do that unless a relay is involved) or down at the electrical service panel, or in a junction box in an unfinished utility space.  (that was possibly later finished?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in your building, but the place I lived that had resistance heat they were attached to the outside of the breaker box or sub-panel.